# symfony 1.4 validate not firing in action.class.php

Tags: symfony-1.4

I'm sure I'm doing something wrong, but I'm trying to implement validators in my app but the validateXXXX doesn't seem to be firing, nor the module/validate/XXXX.yml isn't having an affect.

modules/Register/actions.class.php

Here are some files:

```
class RegisterActions extends sfActions
{
  public function validateIndex()
  {
      error_log("********** in here");
      print " ************ ";
      return false;
  }


  public function executeIndex(sfWebRequest $request)
  {
       .... do something
  }
}
```

....

modules/Register/validate/index.yml
    fields:
        password:
           required:
           .......

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to use Symfony v1.0 validators in v1.4? Things have changed a lot (regarding forms) since v1.0

Comment: Not sure, I'm guessing yes.  This is what the symfony book was talking about, but then again, it's for 1.2.  I would assume this should work as well in 1.4

Comment: Which symfony version are you using? The question was posted with "symfony-1.4" tag, but you are reading 1.2 docs....

Comment: 1.4   I was hoping 1.4 was backwards compatible w/ 1.2

Comment: No, 1.4 only uses the new forms. See http://oldforum.symfony-project.org/index.php/m/93505/ or http://groups.google.com/group/symfony-users/browse_thread/thread/f2a033ea912913c0/2db6fd3662dea474?hide_quotes=no

Comment: 1.3 is backward compatible.  It is the same as 1.4 but includes the 1.0 stuff too.  You should really learn about the form/filters classes though.  They save a lot of time once you get the hang of them.